# Is it possible to use a static template ID to send envelopes in DocuSign using PHP?

Tags: php, laravel-8, docusignapi

My requirement is once admin set template and their variable to send that template to recipient to sign the envelop. Currently I have follow to create template each time using https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/create-template/

Conclusion : How can I avoid to create template and send envelop using my static template id

```
public function sendEngagementLetter(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());
    $businessCityStateZip = $request->businessCity . ' ' . $request->State . ' ' . $request->Zip;
    $token = TokenModel::first();
    $config = new Configuration();
    $config->setHost(env('DOCUSIGN_BASE_URL'));
    $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token['access_token']);
    //dd($config);
    $apiClient = new ApiClient($config);
    $templateApi = new TemplatesApi($apiClient);
    $envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

    $filepath = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path('uploads/Engagement letter.pdf'))));

    $doc_file = 'Engagement letter.pdf';
    $content_bytes = file_get_contents(public_path('uploads/Engagement letter.pdf'));
    $base64_file_content = base64_encode($content_bytes);

    # Create the document model
    $document = new Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
        'document_base64' => $base64_file_content,
        'name' => 'Engagement letter',  # can be different from actual file name
        'file_extension' => 'pdf',  # many different document types are accepted
        'document_id' => '1'  # a label used to reference the doc
    ]);



    # Create the signer recipient model
    # Since these are role definitions, no name/email:
    $signer = new Signer([
        'role_name' => 'signer',
        'recipient_id' => $request->recipient_email,
        'routing_order' => "1"
    ]);
    # create a cc recipient to receive a copy of the documents
    /*$cc = new CarbonCopy([
        'role_name' => 'cc',
        'recipient_id' =>  $request->cc_email,
        'routing_order' => "2"
    ]);*/
    # Create fields using absolute positioning
    # Create a sign_here tab (field on the document)
    $sign_here = new SignHere([
        'document_id' => '1',
        'page_number' => '3',
        'x_position' => '163',
        'y_position' => '272'
    ]);
    $date1 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "1",
        'x_position' => "263",
        'y_position' => "154",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size7",
        'tab_label' => "text",
        'value' => $request->send_date,
        'height' => "20",
        'width' => "150",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);

    $text1 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "1",
        'x_position' => "71",
        'y_position' => "194",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "authorizedSignerName",
        'value' => $request->authorizedSignerName,
        'height' => "10",
        'width' => "150",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $text2 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "1",
        'x_position' => "71",
        'y_position' => "206",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "businessName",
        'value' => $request->businessName,
        'height' => "00",
        'width' => "150",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);


    $text3 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "1",
        'x_position' => "71",
        'y_position' => "219",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "text",
        'value' => $request->businessAddress,
        'height' => "10",
        'width' => "150",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $text4 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "1",
        'x_position' => "71",
        'y_position' => "231",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "text",
        'value' => $businessCityStateZip,
        'height' => "10",
        'width' => "150",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $text5 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "1",
        'x_position' => "99",
        'y_position' => "281",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size10",
        'tab_label' => "text",
        'value' => $request->authorizedSignerName . ',',
        'height' => "10",
        'width' => "150",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $text6 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "1",
        'x_position' => "215",
        'y_position' => "321",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size10",
        'tab_label' => "text",
        'value' => $request->businessName,
        'height' => "20",
        'width' => "200",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $signDate = new DateSigned([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "3",
        'x_position' => "338",
        'y_position' => "288",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "Date Signed 9ac30e67-7a0d-4028-9251-f80a0d947dde",
        'height' => "10",
        'width' => "150",
        'required' => "true"
    ]);
    $signDate2 = new DateSigned([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "3",
        'x_position' => "338",
        'y_position' => "387",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "Date Signed 9ac30e67-7a0d-4028-9251-f80a0d947dde",
        'height' => "10",
        'width' => "150",
        'required' => "true"
    ]);

    $date2 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "2",
        'x_position' => "70",
        'y_position' => "35",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "date2",
        'value' => $request->send_date,
        'height' => "10",
        'width' => "150",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $date3 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "3",
        'x_position' => "70",
        'y_position' => "35",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "date3",
        'value' => $request->send_date,
        'height' => "10",
        'width' => "150",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $Page2 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "2",
        'x_position' => "70",
        'y_position' => "47",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "Page2",
        'value' => 'Page 2 of 3 ',
        'height' => "10",
        'width' => "160",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $Page3 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "3",
        'x_position' => "70",
        'y_position' => "50",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "Page3",
        'value' => 'Page 3 of 3 ',
        'height' => "20",
        'width' => "160",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $businessName2 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "2",
        'x_position' => "70",
        'y_position' => "15",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "businessName2",
        'value' => $request->businessName,
        'height' => "20",
        'width' => "160",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $businessName3 = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "3",
        'x_position' => "70",
        'y_position' => "14",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "businessName3",
        'value' => $request->businessName,
        'height' => "20",
        'width' => "160",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);

    $businessTitle = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "3",
        'x_position' => "160",
        'y_position' => "309",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "businessTitle",
        'value' => $request->authorizedSignerName . ',' . $request->business_title,
        'height' => "20",
        'width' => "160",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);
    $businessTitleSub = new Text([
        'document_id' => "1",
        'page_number' => "3",
        'x_position' => "160",
        'y_position' => "321",
        'font' => "helvetica",
        'font_size' => "size9",
        'tab_label' => "businessTitleSub",
        'value' => $request->businessName . '.',
        'height' => "20",
        'width' => "160",
        'locked' => 'true',
        'required' => "false"
    ]);

    # Add the tabs model to the signer
    # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
    $signer->setTabs(new Tabs([
        'sign_here_tabs' => [
            $sign_here
        ],
        'date_signed_tabs' => [
            $signDate, $signDate2
        ],
        'text_tabs' => [
            $date1,
            $date2,
            $date3,
            $businessName2,
            $businessName3,
            $Page2,
            $Page3,
            $text1,
            $text2,
            $text3,
            $text4,
            $text5,
            $text6,
            $businessTitle,
            $businessTitleSub

        ]
    ]));

    # Template object:
    $template_request = new EnvelopeTemplate([
        'description' => "Hi Kindly sign the Engagement Letter Regards, ",
        'name' => 'Engagement Letter',
        'shared' => "false",
        'documents' => [$document],
        'email_blurb' => "Greetings " . $request->recipient_name . ",<br/><br/><br/>Hi Kindly sign the Engagement Letter for your  opinion <br/><br/>Regards,<br/> Hi",
        'email_subject' => $request->recipient_name . " - Option",
        'recipients' => new Recipients([
            'signers' => [$signer]
            /*'carbon_copies' => [$cc]*/
        ]),
        'status' => "created"
    ]);

    $template = $templateApi->createTemplate(env('DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID'), $template_request);
    $template_id = $template->getTemplateId();
    //dd($template_id);
    /**
     * 
     */

    $token = TokenModel::first();
    // dd($request->all());
    # Create the envelope definition with the template_id
    $envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
        'status' => 'sent',
        "emailBlurb" => "Hi Kindly sign the Engagement Letter for your opinion Regards, ",
        'template_id' => $template_id
    ]);
    # Create the template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
    # to the template
    $signer = new TemplateRole([
        'email' => $request->recipient_email,
        'name' => $request->recipient_name,
        'role_name' => 'signer'
    ]);
    # Create a cc template role.
    $cc = new TemplateRole([
        'email' => $request->cc_email,
        'name' => $request->cc_name,
        'role_name' => 'Developer'
    ]);
    # Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
    $envelope_definition->setTemplateRoles([$signer]);
    //dd($envData);
    $config = new Configuration();
    $config->setHost(env('DOCUSIGN_BASE_URL'));
    $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token['access_token']);
    $api_client = new ApiClient($config);
    $envelope_api = new EnvelopesApi($api_client);
    $results = $envelope_api->createEnvelope(env('DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID'), $envelope_definition);
    $envelope_id = $results->getEnvelopeId();
    /**
     * for delete templete from dashboard start
     */
    $result = (new DeleteTempleteController)->deleteTemplete($template_id);
    /**
     * for delete templete from dashboard start
     * */
    $success_msg = 'Envelopes created successfully';
    $result = array(
        "response" => array(
            'code' => '201',
            'message' => $success_msg,
            'envelope_id' => $envelope_id
        )
    );
    return json_encode($result);
}
```

I want to avoid create template each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote/ shows what you are asking and here is the PHP code which can also be found here - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/Examples/eSignature/UseTemplateService.php

```
private function make_envelope($args)
{
    # Create the envelope definition with the template_id
    $envelope_definition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
       'status' => 'sent', 'template_id' => $args['template_id']
    ]);
    # Create the template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
    # to the template
    $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole([
        'email' => $args['signer_email'], 'name' => $args['signer_name'],
        'role_name' => 'signer'
    ]);
    # Create a cc template role.
    $cc = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole([
        'email' => $args['cc_email'], 'name' => $args['cc_name'],
        'role_name' => 'cc'
    ]);
    # Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
    $envelope_definition->setTemplateRoles([$signer, $cc]);
    return $envelope_definition;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to send dynamic value in in predefined variable in docusign template before send envelope.         If yes can you please provide me example code. In the above my question you can see i have set variable and their value.  Same value I want to send in envalape using template id

Comment: yes, you can do that - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/

Comment: PHP code is in https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/Examples/eSignature/SetTemplateTabValuesService.php